# ASP.NET Use Web.Config to control Port Number to host Web Application Project

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, port, iis-express

I tried to search for this, but didn't found any good explanation.

I am trying to have everything configured on my config files, so it's easier for the user to control the publish and deploy of my application.

In visual studio 2015 I can control the port to host my web application going to:

**Right Click Web Application Project > Properties > Web > Project Url**

Can this be done by configuration file?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can't be done by web.config but you can control it as,

For "Web Application Projects", open ".csproj" file look for the following part.

```
<WebProjectProperties>
      <UseIIS>True</UseIIS>
      <AutoAssignPort>True</AutoAssignPort>
      <DevelopmentServerPort>21128</DevelopmentServerPort>
      <DevelopmentServerVPath>/</DevelopmentServerVPath>
      <IISUrl>http://localhost:21128/</IISUrl>
      <NTLMAuthentication>False</NTLMAuthentication>
      <UseCustomServer>False</UseCustomServer>
      <CustomServerUrl>
      </CustomServerUrl>
      <SaveServerSettingsInUserFile>False</SaveServerSettingsInUserFile>
</WebProjectProperties>
```

Notice the following lines where you can change the port and save it.

```
<DevelopmentServerPort>21128</DevelopmentServerPort>
<DevelopmentServerVPath>/</DevelopmentServerVPath>
<IISUrl>http://localhost:21128/</IISUrl>
```

For the "Website projetcs" you have to open ".sln" file and change the port.

I hope the answer helps.

Comment: It helped mate! Thank you so much! ;)

Comment: It is incomplete. After modifying the project file, changes need to be synchronized to the corresponding applicationHost.config file.